# wso2.1 role based for tenants

Tags: wso2, wso2-identity-server

created and published api in wso2.1 as admin. created roles and rules in identity server as admin and generated token for user created under admin and tried accessing api , it is working fine.

When i created api under admin and subscribed using tenant and created roles and rules in identity server logged in as tenant,create user under teanant and then tried accessing api using the user generated token , it is not working getting "User is not authorized to perform the action"

Please help

Comment: do you mean `super tenant` by `admin`? If yes, please update the question and make it more clear.

Comment: @Bhathiya we are following https://docs.wso2.com/display/AM210/Enabling+Role-Based+Access+Control+Using+XACML this document to create rules. no super tenant here , only admin and tenants users